# gnus error finding parent article from summary mode

Tags: emacs, gnus

Im having trouble with finding the parent article of a sent message in
"Summary-mode".

I press `^` in the sent folder, summary mode, which is bound to the
function "gnus-summary-refere-parent-article". It tells me "No reference
in article x" or "cant find article some-cryptic-id".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advnace for your kind help and time.

jenia

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>t</kbd> from the summary buffer to display the whole message headers, you should see a `References:` header that contains one or more messages IDs.

It is possible that

- either the message does not contain `References`
- or the referenced message does not exist anymore in the server when Gnus tries to fetch it to show it to you

Comment: Yes it does contain References, but I cant fetch the entire thread. It just fails.

Comment: I am having the same problem - the message exists in the server (e.g. if I included it when entering the group by pressing "200" before enter it works), but if it's not on the summary list I would like a way to dynamically fetch and show it.